# Python Indexing Error with Groupby functions

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Import your libraries
import pandas as pd

# Start writing code
sf_public_salaries.groupby('basepay', as_index=False).mean()[['basepay','jobtitle']]
```

getting error message "['jobtitle'] not in index"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/9972-find-the-base-pay-for-police-captains?code_type=2

Comment: If this your actual code so far, I am not seeing where you have defined your data frame.  If you have more code, please include it.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand very well what you want, but if you are trying to get the media based on the 'basepay' and 'jobtitle' columns the following code solves the problem.

```
sf_public_salaries.groupby(['basepay','jobtitle'], as_index=False).mean()
```

The problem is occurring because the result of your code is a table with the column 'basepay' and the columns of numeric values that you can apply the mean function.

To select only the 'basepay' and 'jobtitle' columns just use the following code

```
 sf_public_salaries.groupby(['basepay','jobtitle'], as_index=False).mean()[['basepay', 'jobtitle']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to show two columns 'basepay','jobtitle'  only after group by base mean()..

Comment: Try this: sf_public_salaries.groupby(['basepay','jobtitle'], as_index=False).mean()[['basepay', 'jobtitle']]

Comment: Isn't the job title must be in the group by sections? if I try sf_public_salaries.groupby(['basepay','jobtitle'], as_index=False).mean()[['basepay', 'jobtitle','id']]...can get the id columns yet id column not appear in group by

Comment: What do you need with this code? You are using the average function, but you are discarding the numerical values that were calculated